# Matlab: how to plot from 4-d matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a 4-d matrix contains 1000 pictures.
The shape of matrix is 1000*32*32*3 (1000 is the number of pictures, 32*32 is a 2-d pixel values, 3 is RGB-3 channels).

I was wondering how to display one channel 32*32 values for a picture? or 3 channels 32*32*3?

and can matlab plot the 32*32? or 3 pictures for 3 channels of 32*32?

Comment: RGB-3 channels? are you refering that the `32 X 32` is the pixel count of a color picture? if so, you can simply use `imshow()` to see the image. Also do you want to show one picture out of  1000 that you have?

Comment: thx, I just want to show one picture as an example to see what it looks like.

Comment: Okay simply use `imshow(A(1,:,:,:));`

Comment: I would suggest permuting the dataset (`newA = permute(A, 2,3,4,1);`) so that the image ID is last. Then, if you want to plot a certain image with all channels, you'd access `newA(:,:,:,404)`, and if you want just one channel, you'd do `newA(:,:,2,404)`, and no need to squeeze it anymore.

Comment: @HansHirse Probably that should have been reversed. Keeping the answer and deleting the comment.

Comment: @RC0993 There were several other people suggesting this, so I will undelete my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you use the [`imshow`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imshow.html) command for showing an image, either single-channel (grayscale) or multi-channel (color). In case, you have multiple images stored in the way, you describe, you need to index a specific (grayscale or color) image (or color channel), and possibly need the [`squeeze`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) command to remove dimensions of length 1, which might cause problems with `imshow`.

Please see the following code snippet using some mock-up data:

```matlab
% Mock-up data.
A = uint8(round(255 * rand(1000, 32, 32, 3)));

% Select I-th image.
I = 25;

figure(1);

% Show I-th RGB image.
subplot(2, 2, 1);
imshow(squeeze(A(I, :, :, :)));

% Show I-th red channel image.
subplot(2, 2, 2);
imshow(squeeze(A(I, :, :, 1)));

% Show I-th green channel image.
subplot(2, 2, 3);
imshow(squeeze(A(I, :, :, 2)));

% Show I-th blue channel image.
subplot(2, 2, 4);
imshow(squeeze(A(I, :, :, 3)));
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: The Answer is well drafted and the efforts are nice. But I don't see the reason for using `squeeze`. Can you please elaborate if possible?

Comment: @RC0993 I want to ensure, that `imshow` gets a proper `M x N` (grayscale images) or `M x N x 3` (color images) array as an input (without singleton dimensions), which is not the case for simply using `A(I, :, :, :)`.